# PCL: cylinderes segmentation;point cloud

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

I'm working on my graduation project which consist on segmenting a pillar in point cloudinto its different cylinderes.
First step i did is i extracted the whole cylinder englobing the pillar with PCL library cylinder-segmenting code(c++), wich is composed of the different existing cylinderes seperated by a little gap (as shown in the photo), what i have as proposition is to segment these cylinderes by those gaps the thing that i really have no idea how to code it  and i didn't find similar thing on internet.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnMSD.png) 
and thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Could you add your segmentation code?

Comment: First thx for reading my question.I used this code from Pcl library [link](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/cylinder_segmentation.php#cylinder-segmentation), but with keeping simply the cylinder extraction part and with adding while on radiuslimits to know the exact radius value of my pillar's cylinder.